# Use multiple modals in template vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to create one modal for each row but when i open one modal all the other modals open as well. i suppose this have something to do with the id but i don't know how to fix it.
Using vue@2.6.12

```
<template #cell(add)="row">
  <div>
    <b-button
      v-b-modal="'row'"
      class="bg-dark text-white"
      test-id="showOrHideAddButton"
      size="sm"
    >
      add
    </b-button>
    <b-modal id=row>
      Hello From My Modal!
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Maybe you are using same id for all the modals, try using different id.

Answer (score 1):

As `user3113901` wrote in the comments above `ID's` should be **always** unique. Only `class` could/should be used multiple times.

Here you can see an example how it should work:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button
      v-b-modal="'row1'" <!-- use unique ID here --->
      class="bg-dark text-white"
      test-id="showOrHideAddButton"
      size="sm"
    > add </b-button>
    <b-modal id="row1"> <!-- Here you have to put your id-name into "" --->
      Hello From My First Modal!
    </b-modal>


    <b-button
      v-b-modal="'row2'" <!-- use unique ID here --->
      class="bg-dark text-white"
      test-id="showOrHideAddButton"
      size="sm"
    > add </b-button>
    <b-modal id="row2"> <!-- Here you have to put your id-name into "" --->
      Hello From My Second Modal!
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</template>
```

If you set `v-b-modal` equal to your `id` in your `<b-modal>` and make it all `unique` it should work out!